# Freedom from the guarded island

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

You, a well-known submarinist criminal, are taken prisoner in a perfectly circular island, surrounded by water.

You stand in the center of the island, with the submarinism equipment (don't worry about its weight).

Surrounding the island there is a boat, watching you, that goes 4 times faster than you. That means that even if you go straight in the opposite direction of the boat to flee, the boat will arrive there before you.

If you manage to arrive to the water and the boat's not there, you'll manage to finally flee, since you'd go underwater.

Question is, can you flee the island? If so, how?

EDIT: There's no problem with acceleration nor delay (yes, the boat can go from full speed to full speed in the opposite direction)

$\\$

*Just to sum up*

> *The island is perfectly circular and you are in the center.*
>
> *The boat is always on the border of the island, moves at 4 times your speed, and can go from full speed in one direction to full speed in the opposite.*
>
> *If you arrive at the border of the island and the boat is not there, you are free.*

Comment: And we are to assume no delay by either party, and no acceleration by either party, right? In other words, both the boat and the criminal can either be stopped or moving full speed, correct?

Comment: Correct. Thanks. Well, if somehow needed they could move slower, but they have $\infty$ acceleration.

Comment: @randal'thor I can assure you this can be solved. I summed out what's needed in the logic puzzle for avoid any missunderstood nor thinking that's some kind of riddle. It's a logic and calculation puzzle with everything you need to solve it. Even though, it would be interesting to see a demonstration that you can't flee, if you feel you can't.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans I know! I wasn't criticising the puzzle at all :-) "Dupe" means duplicate: I think this exact question has been asked before on this site.

Comment: @randal'thor Woooops! I missunderstood the word "dupe" then. Sorry. I checked the Urban Dictionary and didn't feel like something nice to say :P

Comment: Found it! http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/the-lake-monster That's essentially the same problem, right?

Comment: Darn. I actually knew the solution to this one. :(

Comment: Not to worry, simple misunderstanding. 'Dupe' has two meanings, one is [to trick or deceive or someone who is the victim of such a deception](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dupe#dupe), the other is simply '[duplicate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dupe#dupe-2)'. Usually here on puzzling.SE 'a dupe' means 'a duplicate question', but there's no particular way for new users to know that, so don't feel bad.